# How use openlayers3 in vuejs?

Tags: node.js, npm, vue.js, openlayers

Through npm install openlayers(4.1.1), I can use openlayers normally in vuejs, but our company custom something base openlayers3.x, so how can I user this custom openlayers? I improt this ol's lib directly, when uses

```
goog.require("ol.Map")
```

it reports

> goog undefined error!

so,  is there any approach to use the custom ol in vuejs? thix.

Comment: Slightly confused -- are you using Google Closure?

Answer (score 0):

You can install particular version of `openlayers`, by mentioning specific version in `package.json`, like following:

```
"dependencies": {
    "openlayers": "3.x.x"
  },
```

After that you remove earlier installed package and do `npm install` in the code directory, which will install the correct version you need.